# download large file chunk by chunk in node js API

Tags: node.js

I have a big file(URL) and want to download it form nodejs API chunk by chunk and send it to the client chunk by chunk :

```
app.get('/download', (req, res, next) => {

    const URL = 'https://www.fec.gov/files/bulk-downloads/2018/indiv18.zip'
    request(URL, function (error, response, body) {
        // send to client 
    });
    
})
```

Comment: Please take a look at the guidelines of [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please clarify what you've already tried to do.

Comment: what's wrong with my question?